# python version is different from set in .bash_profile

Tags: python, linux

I have several python versions on HP-UX.

```
 $ python -V
 Python 2.3.3
 $ which python
 /usr/local/bin/python
 $ echo $PYTHONPATH
 /usr/python-2.5.2/lib/python2.5/site-packages:/usr/python-2.5.2/lib/python2.5
```

In .bash_profile I set I want to use version 2.5.2, so why is used older version and where is set path `/usr/local/bin/python`? How delete this path?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` is not used to select the Python executable. Adjust your `PATH` environment variable instead to handle what locations your shell looks for the Python binary. You can always use version-specific binary names, like `python2.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you may be unclear about the difference between your shell `PATH` (a list of directories in which the shell looks for executable programs) and your `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directories which your Python interpreter will add to `sys.path`, and in which it will look for importable modules and packages).

You are still using Python 2.3.3 because you haven't added the binary directory for Python 2.5.2 (presumably, from your `PYTHONPATH` setting above, `/usr/python-2.5.2/bin`) to your shell's `PATH`. The best place to do this is in your shell initialization file, typically either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`.

You should make sure that this new entry appears BEFORE `/usr/bin/local` to ensure that it is found first, otherwise the `python` command will still find the Python in `/usr/local/bin`. Typically you will need a statement like

```
PATH=/usr/python-2.5.2/bin:$PATH
```

Don't forget to either restart your shell or re-source the initialization file after making this change so it actually affects the shell in which you are testing.

Also note that ANY Python interpreter will always add the necessary `sys.path` entries at startup time to find its installed libraries, so there is no need for a `PYTHONPATH` setting such as you quote above to locate them.